# Webservice to show Java frame

Tags: java, swing, web-services, jframe, jax-ws

I need some suggestions if the below idea for my web-service is feasible and if so, some pointers on how to implement the same.

Web-service Request: Request number
Web-service response: Java Jframe popup on users desktop with details of the request queried from the database.

This web-service would get triggered by clicking on an hyper-link in email notification sent to the user.
I cannot write any code on the client side to read the web-service response and then populate the Java frame.

So is it possible for my web-service to pop-up the JFrame on the users desktop when they query the web-service?
If so, how would I configure my response in the WSDL?

Comment: The short answer is no, a web service can not display a `JFrame`...

Answer (score 2):

The web service runs on the server, the JFrame would run inside a different JVM on the client. So no, the web service can't trigger a JFrame to be shown on the client.
In fact, the web service can't force the client to do anything whatsoever. What the client does with whatever information the web service provides it is totally up to the client, which can be anything, from a Java Swing application (which could use it to display something in a JFrame) to another web service written in Perl (which would likely use it as input for another call or response to something) to an ASP web application (which might display it on a website as a graphic or table of data), to an Oracle SQL query (which may use the result to enter data into a database table which might in turn trigger something else to send an email for example).
That's the very nature of web services, they're utterly agnostic of what and who calls them.